# Error message when Loading shared extension in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, share

I am trying to implement a shared extension in iOS here is my code:

```
class ShareViewController: UIViewController{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem, let itemProvider = extensionItem.attachments?.first else {
            close()
            return
        }
                
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.plain-text"){
            itemProvider.loadItem( forTypeIdentifier: "public.plain-text" as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (data, error) in
                if let stringContent = data as? String{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print( "found string:\(stringContent)")
                     }
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    @objc func close() {
        self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

However when I run the code, even though I get the extracted text, I get the following message in console, with red background!!

```
-[_EXSinkLoadOperator loadItemForTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:expectedValueClass:options:] nil expectedValueClass allowing {(
    NSNumber,
    NSDictionary,
    NSArray,
    NSError,
    NSValue,
    NSDate,
    NSURL,
    _EXItemProviderSandboxedResource,
    UIImage,
    NSUUID,
    NSData,
    NSString
)}
```

Any ideas what this is??
Thanks
Reza